# Android Edittext requestFocus() not working?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was searching for whole day, try most of solutions founded, but still not work. Is there a bug of `EditText` on `Android`?

I have 2 `EditText` fields (call `edtA and edtB`), `edtA` is required field. When I leave `edtA` blank and input to `edtB`, then Enter, I want it focus back to `edtA` and show error popup "Required field is empty!".

[image]

But now, the cursor stills in `edtB, edtA` is not focused and show error `popup`

[image]

Here is my code when `edtB` press Enter, `edtNO_CON` is edtA I mentioned above:

```
edtNO_CAR.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mNoCon)) {
                        edtNO_CON.requestFocus();
                        edtNO_CON.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                    } else if (edtNO_CAR.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                        // Do something
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And this is XML of edtA:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmNO_CONTAINER"
        style="@style/text14Black"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

Anyone can help?
Thank for your time.

**Update:**
After tried all your suggestions but nothing changes, I decided to use `setOnEditorActionListener` instead of `setOnKeyListener`, and now it works!
Here is my updated code:

```
edtNO_CAR.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
                    || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                String strNoCon = edtNO_CON.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strNoCon)) {
                    edtNO_CON.requestFocus();
                    edtNO_CON.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                } else if (edtNO_CAR.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add this `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your xml file is to authorize the focus

Comment: I tried and it didn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

first call the setEror and then call the requestFocus

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these 2 lines:

android:focusable="true"
android:cursorVisible="true"

If it does not work. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **return@setOnKeyListener true** on your function key listener

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).